# Setting a session through php and selectively loading html

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I'm new to php and web server technology so please bear with me. I'm trying to have a webpage that has a form. The form is submitted and if the data is correct it reloads and loads different html. Here's my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = "";
$_SESSION['pass'] = "";

echo "This is the front page. Please input your data";

if($_SESSION['user'] != 'asdf'){
    $html = file_get_contents('scripts/login.html');
    echo $html;
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
}

if($_SESSION['user'] == "awedes"){
   $html =  file_get_contents('scripts/strsd.html');
   echo $html;
 }
```

So far I think this is good. I have a form, and with a login, it says submit. I want the page to reload, but this time I want to set the SESSION['user'] = to the input. The form will look something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My question: How can I set the SESSION['user'] so that when I click form submit the 'user' input becomes the SESSION. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

Please remove session initialisation  lines

```
$_SESSION['user'] = "";
$_SESSION['pass'] = "";
```

Reason is, whenever you submit the form session get empty so that below condition not working and also make sure

```
     if($_SESSION['user'] != 'asdf')
```

above line, will it need to work on if empty user value?,

```
echo "This is the front page. Please input your data";

 if($_SESSION['user'] != 'asdf'){
        $html = file_get_contents('scripts/login.html');
        echo $html;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    }

    if($_SESSION['user'] == "awedes"){
       $html =  file_get_contents('scripts/strsd.html');
     echo $html;
   }
```